# SwiftUI absolute beginner on 10.14.6

Tags: swiftui

I installed XCode and opened a new project using SwiftUI but for the following reason it is impossible to run the builded application. I did use the default code and press run.

I get the following message : "**minimum deployment target. Change your project’s minimum deployment target or upgrade MacBook ...**".

I tried to change the deployement target but immediately I have several Swift Compiler Error like this one : "**'some' return types are only available in macOS 10.15.0 or newer**"

I'm running a MacBook Pro with 10.14.6. Is there a way to find the source code for a buildable SwiftUI application on my computer ?

I cannot update to 10.15.0 so I'm looking for other advice or explanation. Maybe for some sourcecode I could use on my MacBook compatible with the Swift Compiler I have.

Thanks.

Comment: `SwiftUI` requires Catalina (macOS 10.15). Unlike in iOS there is no simulator.

Comment: If you can't upgrade obtain a VM (VMWare Fusion, Parallels, Virtual Box) and install Catalina on it. Provided you're not doing graphics where hardware acceleration is required then it should do you fine until you can upgrade to/get a machine with Catalina.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answers. I cannot update my OS and XCode won't build anything if I don't install Catalina first. I was hopping for an other solution, your answers helped me to focus on the right directions so I searched the web a little bit more and read articles on Mac OS X GUI Programming.

I'm now looking at Python : https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming

I'm a little bit disappointed because I wanted to start something new with Swift. But, there is a good lesson here, and I'll do with what is possible given what I have :) Back in the days, for GUIs, I've used Web UI, Java and Qt and I was hoping for something new. I guess that I'll pursue my search to create nice and awesome native Mac OS X application both later and on the side.

Thanks.

Comment: You can also *create nice and awesome native Mac OS X application* without SwiftUI

Comment: @vadian I'm all hear ! I've searched the web and so far found tutorials on Cocoa but it was not clear if it is still worth it or not ? Maybe you can give me some insight ?